# Django server does not serve static files for admin page

Tags: python, html, django, nginx, gunicorn

I have a Django server running with nginx and gunicorn.

All static files are served correctly, only the admin page has no css, js, etc. .
I already ran `collectstatic` and restarted nginx and gunicorn.

Nothing changed.

**What can I do?**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mention the locations of your `staticfiles_dirs` in `settings.py`. Also remember to mention the locations of your static files in a dynamic format instead of hard coding them in your html document.And make sure to `load static` in `base.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sample code in your settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    '/var/www/static/'
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

After this use the following command in terminal:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This should create the static folder and copy all the static objects inside